# Composer не работает с personal access token

Tags: composer

Генерирую `personal access token` в `github`(приватный репозиторий). Добавляю его в **composer** через команду composer `config -g github-oauth.github.com <token>` делаю `composer install` и получаю ошибку:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
> Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters:""

И в принципе не даёт ни одну команду выполнить.

Версия **composer**: `Composer version 2.0.6`

**UPD**

Удали токен и выполнил `composer install`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом пробую повторно любую команду композитора и получаю опять туже ошибку.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Гитхаб изменил формат у токена авторизации. Вам нужно обновить компосер. [Подробности](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/9757)

Comment: @Jigius оформите как ответ. Спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гитхаб изменил формат у токена авторизации. Вам нужно обновить компосер.

[Подробности](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/9757)